# How to use JasperReports json metadata exporter to produce an array of objects that contain objects

Tags: json, jasper-reports

I have data as simple as below is a jasper report:

| firstName | lastName |
| --- | --- |
| john | carter |
| mary | ann |
| jack | thomas |

and would like to export it to json. I'm trying to use Json metadata as described [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/subreport/index.html#jsonmetadataexport).

I'm able to get the output below:

```
[
    {
        "firstName": "john",
        "lastName": "carter"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "mary",
        "lastName": "ann"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "jack",
        "lastName": "thomas"
    }
]
```

by using the schema below:

```
{
  _type: 'array',
  _children: {
    _type: 'object',
    firstName: 'value',
    lastName: 'value'
  }
}
```

and these properties in the text fields:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.json.path" value="firstName"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.json.path" value="lastName"/>
```

The problem arises when I try to generate a more complicated (but not that much) json. As below:

```
[
    {
        "person": {
            "firstName": "john",
            "lastName": "carter"
        }
    },
    {
        "person": {
            "firstName": "mary",
            "lastName": "ann"
        }
    },
    {
        "person": {
            "firstName": "jack",
            "lastName": "thomas"
        }
    }
]
```

The schema changes of course to this:

```
{
  _type: 'array',
  _children: {
    _type: 'object',
    person: {
      _type: 'object',
      firstName: 'value',
      lastName: 'value'
    }
  }
}
```

I changed the path in the text fields to this:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.json.path" value="person.firstName"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.json.path" value="person.lastName"/>
```

What I get is this malformed json:

```
[
    {
        "person": {
            "firstName": "john",
            "lastName": "carter"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "mary",
            "lastName": "ann"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "jack",
            "lastName": "thomas"
        }
    }
]
```

Do you guys have any idea what I'm doing wrong? There is so little resources on this Json metadata exporter, even from JasperReports. Sometimes I think it's a half baked obscure feature nobody uses or cares about.

Answer (score -1):

This is an Array []

```
[
    {
        "person": 
        [
            {
                "firstName": "john",
                "lastName": "carter"
            },
            {
                "firstName": "mary",
                "lastName": "ann"
            },
            {
                "firstName": "jack",
                "lastName": "thomas"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).